# JTextField problem with ActionEvent getModifiers method

Tags: java, events

When I hit the enter key into a `JTextField` and I'm pressing one modifier key (like Ctrl or Alt) the `ActionEvent` is not fired and thus I can't check the modifier key just pressed.

Why is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

For Swing widgets, key binding should be done through `InputMap` and `ActionMap` (although the "obsolete" `registerKeyboardAction` is simpler). See [Keyboard Bindings in Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/special_report/kestrel/keybindings.html) in the old Swing Connection, and the `JComponent` API docs.

The Pluggable Look & Feel rather gets in the way of mapping input events onto actions. Exactly what happens with `ActionEvent` is up to the current PL&F. Application code directly registering `KeyListener` generally isn't a good idea in Swing. Some components are made up of other smaller components, meaning `InputEvent`s may or may not get passed on. Input events may get interpreted to perform more than one operation. Generally the whole thing is a mess.